# Restrict VPN client traffic to certain domains/IP

Tags: vpn, domain, ip, routing, openvpn

Is there any way to restrict a VPN client to only route certain traffic via the VPN and the rest via their local gateway?

For example: traffic to a certain IP or domain gets routed across the VPN and all other requests do not.

Let me know if you need more details.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible to only route traffic to a certain FQDN via the VPN. The alternative of using the IP address is not sufficient in this case as it can change. Thank you anyhow.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: please check this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/1127638/146523

Answer (score 4):

I see this question tagged as openvpn, so I'Lll give an openvpn answer.

In openvpn you can make server "push" certain routes to the clients

openvpn server.conf

```
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 1.2.3.0 255.255.255.0"
```

The client must have 'pull' in its config file.

see man openvpn(8) under --pull and --push

Comment: Thanks Aleksandar.

I ran through the openvpn man pages and I am still unable to find how to only pass traffic to a FQDN (or even a specific URI) via the VPN, while the rest of the traffic is routed via the client's standard gateway.

Comment: on a vpn level you can't do it by FQDN or URI, only per IP address, thats all a VPN knows about

i.e. if you only want to route serverfault

> host serverfault.com
serverfault.com has address 69.59.196.212

your push will then be

push "route 69.59.196.212 255.255.255.255"

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just add route commands to the openvpn configuration.  Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Hi womble,

Would it be server side then? I would have thought that the configuration had to made client side.

I would appreciate more details. If you have a short example if would be even greater.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FreshTomato here. I managed to only redirect 3 destination IPs to the VPN.

Below is the OpenVPN custom configuration:

```
allow-pull-fqdn
route-nopull
script-security 2
up /opt/openvpn-routes.sh
```

Then the script mentioned above:

```bash
root@router:/tmp/home/root# cat /opt/openvpn-routes.sh 
#!/bin/sh
ip route add 204.11.51.251/32  dev tun11 # www.linksysinfo.org
ip route add 201.54.48.99/32   dev tun11 # www12.senado.leg.br
ip route add 34.160.111.145/32 dev tun11 # ifconfig.me
```

The /opt mount point was set up following the instructions from https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki/Install-on-TomatoUSB-and-FreshTomato